# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in da.Fill(dt1)

Tags: c#

Why I recieved the error

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

in line `da.Fill(dt1);`

```
if (Convert.ToUInt16(BestScoreID) != 0)
{
   connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
   command1.Connection = connection;
   command1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MainData where ID ='"+BestScoreID+"'";
   OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command1);
   DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt1);
   dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
   connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `ID` column? Sounds like it's numeric. If so, delete single quotes. As a better, use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use sql parameters instead of string concatenation to provide parameters. Otherwise you are vulnerable to sql injection and conversion errors.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
using(var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MainData where ID=@ID", connection))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.SmallInt).Value = short.Parse(BestScoreID);
    // no need to open/close the connection with dataadapter.Fill:
    da.Fill(dt1);
}
```